How do you convert a string to utf-16 in javascript?
I want to know how to convert a string to UTF-16 in Javascript
I tried charCodeAt() but it only gave me the UTF-16 code of only one character but I want to encode an entire string into UTF-16. I also tried other methods but they have failed. I am using code.org.

Strings are UTF-16 encoded by default in JavaScript.

function stringToUTF16Array(str) {
    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2);
    let view = new Uint16Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        view[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return view;
}

let str = "test";
let utf16Array = stringToUTF16Array(str);

console.log(utf16Array);

You can use a loop to loop through each character and convert it

Citation needed on the posted coded, previously posted in this answer which cites a Chrome developers blog as its source.  Reaching a reputation of 3000 will gain you the moderator privilege of casting close and open votes
